# how to concatenate multiple textarea into one textarea and split that textarea into multiple textarea dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Also there should not be any visible seperator like (:) to split the textarea. Currently I have done it with (:) seperator. I need to separate it with a span tag may be which will be unvisible.  Here is the code given below:

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="text-center text-primary">TextArea Concatenate and Revert</h3>
  <form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <textarea id="text_area_1" rows="14" cols="100"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 border">
      <img src="images/signature.png" alt="signature">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
      <textarea id="text_area_2" rows="6" cols="50"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
      <textarea id="text_area_3" rows="6" cols="50"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p>স্মারক নম্বর: ০৫.৪৫.৩৯০০.০১১.৬১.০০১.১৭.৫৬/১</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 border">
      <img src="images/signature.png" alt="signature">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
      <textarea id="text_area_4" rows="6" cols="50"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
      <textarea id="text_area_5" rows="6" cols="50"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="concatenate()">Concatenate</button>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <textarea id="text_area_6" rows="40" cols="180"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="revert()">Revert</button>
</div>
```

Style:

```
.border{
border: 1px solid;}
```

Javascript:

```
<script>

    var one = document.getElementById("text_area_1");
    var two = document.getElementById("text_area_2");
    var three = document.getElementById("text_area_3");
    var four = document.getElementById("text_area_4");
    var five = document.getElementById("text_area_5");
    var six = document.getElementById("text_area_6");


    function concatenate(){
      six.value = one.value + ":" + two.value+ ":" + three.value+ ":" + four.value+ ":" + five.value;
      one.value = "";
      two.value = "";
      three.value = "";
      four.value = "";
      five.value = "";
      }

    function revert(){
        var val = six.value.split(":");
        one.value = val[0];
        two.value = val[1];
        three.value = val[2];
        four.value = val[3];
        five.value = val[4];
        six.value = "";
        }

</script>
```

Comment: xy problem why do you need multiple textareas?

Comment: use global variables - when you `concatenate` the strings the global variables will be populated with the appropriate content and can then be `revert(ed)`

Comment: In the beginning I want to input some text into multiple textarea then it will be concatenated and show in another textarea. When I will click on the revert button then the big textarea will split and go back to it's previous multiple textarea. That's why I need multiple textarea. @madalin

Comment: @ShibleeSadik inputs accept only plain text so what you suggest is impossible you will need a custom text editor

Comment: @madalinivascu I want to input plain text only. :)

Comment: @ShibleeSadik then  stick with the `:` or use another input splitter character(set)

Answer (score 0):

By using a global variable ( or variables ) you can assign the values when the `concatenate` button is clicked and they will be available later when the `revert` button is clicked.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Concatenate() & revert()</title>
        <script>
            var texts={
                'text_area_1':'',
                'text_area_2':'',
                'text_area_3':'',
                'text_area_4':'',
                'text_area_5':''
            };
            var target='text_area_6';

            function $(id){
                return document.getElementById(id);
            }
            function combine(o,b){
                if( typeof( o )=='object' ){
                    var t=[];
                    var a=arguments;
                    var e=( a.length==3 ) ? a[2]:false;
                    var s=( a.length==4 ) ? a[3]:'=';
                    for( var n in o ){
                        if( b && typeof( o[ n ] )=='object' ) t.push( combine( o[ n ], b, e, s ) );
                        else t.push( o[ n ] );
                    }
                    return t;
                }
                return o;   
            }
            function concatenate(){
                var keys=Object.keys(texts);
                for( k in keys ){
                    texts[ keys[ k ] ]=$( keys[ k ] ).value;
                    $( keys[ k ] ).value='';
                }
                $(target).value=combine( Object.values(texts).join(' '),0 );
            }
            function revert(){
                var keys=Object.keys( texts );
                for( k in keys ){
                    $( keys[ k ] ).value=texts[ keys[ k ] ];
                }
                $(target).value='';
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h3 class="text-center text-primary">TextArea Concatenate and Revert</h3>
      <form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
          <textarea id="text_area_1" rows="14" cols="100">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed id imperdiet mi. Donec velit orci, consectetur sit amet mi id, eleifend pretium lorem. Integer orci ex, suscipit sit amet dui id, mollis condimentum elit. Fusce blandit quis magna eu malesuada. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam tristique nunc at mauris porta elementum. Pellentesque ut lacinia metus, lacinia mollis odio. Praesent sed viverra metus. Phasellus non tristique nisl, ut congue erat. Aliquam neque leo, blandit eu varius id, mattis vel tellus.</textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 border">
          <img src="images/signature.png" alt="signature">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
          <textarea id="text_area_2" rows="6" cols="50">Etiam ullamcorper pulvinar tincidunt. Suspendisse scelerisque commodo nisl eget volutpat. Cras tristique quis eros lobortis blandit. Duis sed pellentesque est. Aenean sem ex, ultrices nec enim pharetra, placerat gravida turpis. Proin ultricies ultrices tellus ac condimentum. Aliquam nisl dolor, vulputate vitae risus vel, porta pulvinar ligula. Fusce dapibus rutrum pulvinar.</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
          <textarea id="text_area_3" rows="6" cols="50">Sed eget rhoncus sapien, in dapibus metus. Mauris porta, massa nec sodales dignissim, dui est accumsan lorem, vel vulputate velit mi eget velit. In a suscipit eros, eget hendrerit dui. In in imperdiet tellus.</textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <p>?????? ?????: ??.??.????.???.??.???.??.??/?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 border">
          <img src="images/signature.png" alt="signature">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
          <textarea id="text_area_4" rows="6" cols="50">Ut pellentesque nunc neque, nec mattis nisl commodo at. Aenean dictum tellus diam, vel scelerisque eros euismod quis. Nunc tellus mauris, suscipit at metus sed, pretium auctor arcu. Curabitur pretium pellentesque dictum. Pellentesque lacinia condimentum dictum. Praesent quis euismod lorem.</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
          <textarea id="text_area_5" rows="6" cols="50">Sed justo diam, commodo consectetur porta vitae, ultricies non ipsum. Donec eget magna odio. Fusce in orci vel erat fringilla accumsan in sit amet lacus. Fusce diam sapien, ullamcorper quis auctor ac, tempor ut quam. Duis iaculis convallis nunc, sed faucibus erat pharetra quis.</textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="concatenate()">Concatenate</button>
      </form>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <textarea id="text_area_6" rows="40" cols="180"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="revert()">Revert</button>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```